# Django admin commands with/without args

Tags: python, django, args

is it possible to have on the same admin command class option to run it with or without args.

like having if args == "" (run this command) else: (run this)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just check 'args' as passed to the handle method like this:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'prints no args if there are no args'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if len(args) == 0:
            print 'no args'
        else:
            for pkid in args:
                print pkid
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is.... if I put some number as args (in my case it will be pk value (digit)) than I will run a code that will bring specific pk id. and if my args are empty I will run a different code to bring all id's from db.

Comment: @yaniv14 - I updated my answer to check for no args rather than a specific argument.  I think the updated code should be closer to what you are trying to do.